# Split string by a string?

Tags: vb6, split

If I have a string like:

```
Dim someStr As String
someStr = "NODE TEST              ACCESS"
```

I want to split that string by two spaces. It looks like the `Split()` function accepts a character and not a full string for what to split on.

What's the most simple way to split a string by a string (two spaces in this case)? Splitting by two or more spaces is fine. I'm not looking to split at exactly two.

Comment: Do you mean two spaces or two or more spaces?  See my comment to lardymonkey's answer below.

Comment: @BobRodes Two or more, but there's no guarantee it'll be more than say 2 or 3 spaces.

Comment: Just to be entirely clear, then, do you want to split every two spaces into a separate element, or do you want to use any number of spaces over one as a single delimiter?

Comment: @BobRodes Ah okay. Two or more is fine, it doesn't have to split every 2 spaces.

Comment: Maybe you can use http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html

Comment: @user2864740 yes, you can do that too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after getting a few clarifications to the OP's requirements, we will need to augment lardymonkey's idea a bit.  So:

```
Dim someStr As String
Dim someArray() as String
Dim cLen As Integer 'Keep a count of the current characters in the string

someStr = "NODE TEST              ACCESS"

'Strip off one space at a time from groups of >2 spaces
Do
    cLen = Len(someStr)
    someStr = Replace(someStr, Space$(3), Space$(2)) 
Loop Until cLen = Len(someStr) 'No more replacements were made in the current iteration

'Now you can use lardymonkey's idea
someArray = Split(Replace$(someStr,"  ","|"),"|")
```

Comment: I take it that you mean `Space$(3), Space$(2)`, not `Spaces(3), Spaces(2)` ?

Comment: Oops!  I actually meant the Space function.  I don't usually use the $ afterwards; bad habit really since VB uses a Variant internally when you don't.  Thanks Mark, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading the OP's qusetion correctly they want to split the string without getting empty results in the return. Using regular expressions greatly simplifies this. First add a reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**. Then you can adapt the function below to your specific needs.

*Note there is no error handling in the example*.

```
Private Function SplitString(ByVal vPattern As String, ByVal vText As String, ByRef Result() As String) As Integer
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim intMatchCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    intMatchCount = 0
    regex.Pattern = vPattern
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    Set colMatches = regex.Execute(vText)
    If regex.Test(vText) = True Then
        intMatchCount = colMatches.Count
        ReDim Result(0 To intMatchCount)
        For i = 0 To intMatchCount - 1
            Result(i) = colMatches(i).Value
        Next i
        Set colMatches = Nothing    ' I don't know if this is needed, but playing it safe
    End If
    Set regex = Nothing    ' I don't know if this is needed, but playing it safe

    SplitString = intMatchCount

End Function
```

To use the function add a multi-line textbox and a command button to a form and paste in the following code.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim aryMatches() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strText As String

    Text1.Text = ""
    strPattern = "\w+"
    strText = "NODE TEST              ACCESS"
    If SplitString(strPattern, strText, aryMatches) > 0 Then
        For i = LBound(aryMatches) To UBound(aryMatches)
            Text1.SelText = aryMatches(i) & vbCrLf
            Text1.SelStart = Len(Text1.Text)
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regex to replace two or more spaces with any character and then split on that character.

1. Add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions".
2. Do something like this:

   ```
   Dim a() As String

   With New RegExp
       .Pattern = "\s{2,}"
       a = Split(.Replace(someStr, "~"), "~")
   End With
   ```

Comment: Just use `ChrW(&HE1B6)` instead of the `~` or anything else from unicode's *Private Use Area (PUA)* to be safe from collisions.

Comment: @wqw You're right, of course. I was just trying to keep it simple for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep the spaces you could try using the replace command to replace every two characters with another single character that you can split on

```
Dim someStr As String
Dim someArray() as String

someStr = "NODE TEST              ACCESS"
someArray = split(Replace$(someStr,"  ","|"),"|")
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but if you have ten spaces you will get five | characters, and get some array values with empty strings in them.  I suspect the OP hasn't explained himself quite clearly, and means two or more spaces.  His "full string" makes me even more suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

a slight change to the answers of lardymonkey andBoBrodes

why would you replace the spaces with "|" ? the original string could contain "|" by itself which would give unexpected results

it's better to replace the double spaces by single ones :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim someStr As String
  Dim strArray() As String
  someStr = "NODE TEST              ACCESS"
  someStr = RemoveDouble(someStr, " ")
  strArray = Split(someStr, " ")
End Sub

Private Function RemoveDouble(strSource As String, strRemove As String)
  Dim strReturn As String
  Dim strDouble As String
  strDouble = strRemove & strRemove
  strReturn = Replace(strSource, strDouble, strRemove)
  Do While InStr(strReturn, strDouble) > 0
    strReturn = Replace(strReturn, strDouble, strRemove)
  Loop
  RemoveDouble = strReturn
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This time, a completely different answer - using the more "primitive" VB string functions. If you are interested in such things, this is roughly twice as fast as Bob Rhode's answer.

Essentially, I move through the string, noting the positions of two or more spaces, and then move one character at a time until a non-space is found. Using this information, we can pull substrings out from the correct position in the string, and copy them into a pre-allocated string array. I allocate the array in chunks of 64. If we go above the number of elements in the array, we reallocate it by another chunk of 64.

```
Private Function SplitOnMultiSpaces2(ByVal someStr As String) As String()

    Const someStringsChunkLen   As Long = 64
    Dim someStringLen           As Long
    Dim someStrings()           As String
    Dim someStringsIndex        As Long
    Dim multiSpacePos           As Long
    Dim nextPos                 As Long

    ' Cache the length of the string.
    someStringLen = Len(someStr)

    ' Allocate one chunk of elements initially.
    ReDim someStrings(0 To someStringsChunkLen - 1)

    ' Point to the first element in the array.
    someStringsIndex = 0

    ' Find the first position of more than 1 space.
    multiSpacePos = InStr(1, someStr, "  ", vbBinaryCompare)

    ' Special case. If no multi spaces were found, then simply return a single string in the array.
    If multiSpacePos = 0 Then
        someStrings(0) = someStr
    Else
        ' Point the beginning of the next string to the first character in <someStr>.
        nextPos = 1
        Do
            ' Copy the "next string" into the next available array element.
            someStrings(someStringsIndex) = Mid$(someStr, nextPos, multiSpacePos - nextPos)

            ' Move to the second space in the multi-spaces, and iterate until we find a non-space (space = ASCII 32).
            nextPos = multiSpacePos + 1
            Do
                If nextPos = someStringLen Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                nextPos = nextPos + 1
            Loop While AscW(Mid$(someStr, nextPos, 1)) = 32

            ' We now pointing to the beginning of the next string - or at the end of the string.
            ' Look for the next multi space.
            multiSpacePos = InStr(nextPos, someStr, "  ", vbBinaryCompare)

            ' Point to the next array element.
            someStringsIndex = someStringsIndex + 1
            ' If this array element points beyond the current upper bound of the array, then add another chunk to the array.
            ' We look at the remainder from dividing <someStringsIndex> by <someStringsChunkLen>.
            ' For instance, if this is element 64, then this is 64 / 64 = 1 remainder 0.
            ' We can use this simple test because we only resize upwards.
            If (someStringsIndex Mod someStringsChunkLen) = 0 Then
                ' e.g. resize upper bound to 64 + 64 - 1 = 127.
                ReDim Preserve someStrings(0 To someStringsIndex + someStringsChunkLen - 1)
            End If
        Loop Until multiSpacePos = 0

        ' If we aren't at the end of the string, then copy the remaining values.
        If nextPos <> someStringLen Then
            someStrings(someStringsIndex) = Mid$(someStr, nextPos)
        End If
    End If

    ' Resize down to the proper size.
    ReDim Preserve someStrings(0 To someStringsIndex)

    ' Return the string array.
    SplitOnMultiSpaces2 = someStrings()

End Function
```

Comment: Twice as fast, really?  Interesting.  Did you benchmark that?  I'm not asking defensively; I'm genuninely interested.